# PHP Mail attechment dont work

Tags: php, mailer

I have a problem because my file attechment via a php doesn't work. I tried different tutorials. My last try was the code here:

```
if($isValid === true) {

    // Submit Mail
    $mail = new SimpleMail();
    $mail->setTo(YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS, YOUR_COMPANY_NAME)
    ->setSubject('Neue Mietanfrage')
    ->setFrom(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email-address']), htmlspecialchars($_POST['first-name'].' '.$_POST['last-name']))
    ->addGenericHeader('X-Mailer', 'PHP/' . phpversion())
    ->addGenericHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset="utf-8"')
    ->setMessage(createMessage($_POST))
    ->setWrap(100);

    $mail->send();


    // Submit Client Mail
    $mailClient = new SimpleMail();
    $mailClient->setTo(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email-address']), htmlspecialchars($_POST['first-name'].' '.$_POST['last-name']))
    ->setSubject('Ihre Mietanfrage bei '.YOUR_COMPANY_NAME)
    ->setFrom(YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS, YOUR_COMPANY_NAME)
    ->addGenericHeader('X-Mailer', 'PHP/' . phpversion())
    ->addGenericHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset="utf-8"')
    ->setMessage(createClientMessage($_POST))
    ->setWrap(100);

        $mailClient->send();

    $result = array(
        'result' => 'success', 
        'msg' => array('Ihre Reservierung wurde erfolgreich übermittelt.')
        );

    echo json_encode($result);

} else {
    $result = array(
        'result' => 'error', 
        'msg' => $isValid
        );

    echo json_encode($result);
}

//*** Attachment ***//  
if($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"] != "")  
{  
$strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"];  
$strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"])));  
$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";  
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n";  
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";  
$strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";  
$strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";  
}




<input type="file" name="fileAttach" id="fileAttach" hidden>
```

Why doesnt that worked for me? I just followed the tutorial but nothing helped. Do you have any idea what I have to do? The other informations like the text fields are sending without problems.

I get the informations from that form with javascript. Does that script pay any role why the email doesnt send with the attachment?

```js
$( "#umzug-form" ).submit(function() {

  $('#umzug-form-msg').addClass('hidden');
  $('#umzug-form-msg').removeClass('alert-success');
  $('#umzug-form-msg').removeClass('alert-danger');

  $('#umzug-form input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/umzug.php",
    data: $("#umzug-form").serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data)  {

      if('success' == data.result)
      {
        $('#umzug-form-msg').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn().removeClass('hidden').addClass('alert-success');
        $('#umzug-form-msg').html(data.msg[0]);
        $('#umzug-form input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#umzug-form')[0].reset();
      }

      if('error' == data.result)
      {
        $('#umzug-form-msg').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn().removeClass('hidden').addClass('alert-danger');
        $('#umzug-form-msg').html(data.msg[0]);
        $('#umzug-form input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
      }

    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Please explain "doesnt work" do you get an error anywhere? Have you dissected the resulting email?

Comment: oh sorry.. the file doesn't send so i get no attechment. So nothing happens with the uploaded file

Comment: dont use mail(), use phpmailer, save your self a lot of pain

Comment: I don't get it. Is this your actual code? If it is, then no wonder your file is not sent, you are setting `$strHeader` and adding the content of your uploaded file to it, but you never use this variable to add the header to your mail object!

Comment: Which tutorial are you trying to follow?

Comment: Since you're not telling, nobody knows what `SimpleMail` class that code is using. Chances are it has an `->addAttachment()` anyway. Some `print`/debug statements also wouldn't hurt. A barebones "doesn't work" observation will get you nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't adding the file to the mail object anywhere.

[SimpleMail](https://github.com/eoghanobrien/php-simple-mail#example-of-sending-an-email-with-attachments) provides the method `addAttachment` to add attachments to your email.

I'm extending your code with the needed lines:

```
// Submit Mail
$mail = new SimpleMail();
$mail->setTo(YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS, YOUR_COMPANY_NAME)
    ->setSubject('Neue Mietanfrage')
    ->setFrom(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email-address']), htmlspecialchars($_POST['first-name'].' '.$_POST['last-name']))
    ->addGenericHeader('X-Mailer', 'PHP/' . phpversion())
    ->addGenericHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset="utf-8"')
    ->setMessage(createMessage($_POST))
    ->setWrap(100);

// add the following lines to your code
if (isset($_FILES['fileAttach']['tmp_name'])) {
    $mail->addAttachment(
        $_FILES['fileAttach']['tmp_name'],
        $_FILES['fileAttach']['name']
    );
}

$mail->send();
```

SimpleMail will load the contents of the file by itself.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately the email doesn't send at all now.

Comment: I added the javascript.. Can that script be the reason why the email doesn't send?

Comment: @TimN Do you get any errors using the code in this answer? @naitsirch has not closed one **parentheses** in the `if` statement. So the correct code for that line should be `if (isset($_FILES['fileAttach']['tmp_name'])) {`

Comment: @EhsanT Thanks for your hint. I have added the missing parentheses.